# uri for aws_api_gateway_integration for type AWS (integration) to DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, terraform

I am creating infrastructure with terraform with API Gateway connecting to DynamoDb API. I am creating `resource` `aws_api_gateway_integration` to define the integration with DynamoDb with `type` attribute set as `AWS`.

But somehow i am unable to get the `uri` value right for db.

Documentation says it should be of format `arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}`.

Current value configured is `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:dynamodb:GetItem`.

I am not sure what is `service_api`. Did anyone encounter this before? Kindly help.

Answer (score 17):

This also took me some time to figure out, I think the DynamoDB API-Gateway Integration deserves a dedicated example in the Terraform docs similar to Lambda. Actually `service_api` just refers to the DynamoDB Action (which you would also enter in the AWS Api Gateway Console `Action` field) prefixed with the literal `action/`. So the following block eventually worked for my PUT request mapping:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "my-integration" {
  type = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:dynamodb:action/PutItem"
  # (...)
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to describe this a little more, I'm trying to do the same thing and am having difficulty understanding how to connect the dynamodb with api gateway, I can put in what you have above but i get: "Role ARN must be specified for AWS integrations"

The docs mention something like this:

arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:012345678901:function:my-func/invocations

So if i was to do similar:

arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:dynamodb:action/PutItem/arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:012345678901 ? But this doesnt work

Comment: The Gateway needs permissions to interact with your dynamodb tables, so typically you would create an IAM Role and associate a Policy that grants the necessary actions such as `dynamodb:PutItem`. If your role is managed by terraform you can just use the resource itself to resolve the _ARN_, and assign it as credentials in the _aws_api_gateway_integration_ setup, e.g.  `credentials = "${aws_iam_role.api-gateway.arn}"`. [Here's](https://github.com/tillkuhn/yummy-aws/blob/master/terraform/terraform-apigw.tf) a full example I use in my project, hope this helps.